# How to share full path of folder in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, sharing, permissions, google-workspace-for-business

We use Google drive for storing the files of our company and we share files and projects with coworkers, no problem with that.

Imagine my drive like this:

```
Root_folder
  -F1
    -SubF1
    -SubF2
  -F2
```

The problem is we have all files structured and ordered in different folders, and when I share a folder, only that's shared, not the full path to the file.

Is it possible to share the full path in an easy way? 
This is, only allowing the user to acccess the file or folder I shared, without seeing the others? 
If in the above example, if I share SubF2 with the user, The other user should see this structure:

```
Root_folder
  -F1
    -SubF2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you share main (Root_Folder) with all users, they will see the full path and the structure of the ordered files and folders.
And control sharing permissions for only your personal files and folders.

But for new edits, they will not receive share notification.

Comment: I didn't understand your point. I already have the full structure (code A above). Imagine F1 is the Projects folder, and F2 the finance folder. When I add a team member (developer), I need him to access only the SubF2 (a specific project, not other projects nor the finance folder). But I need him to see the full path, so when I assign another project (i.e. SubF3), he'll see that inside the folder F1. If I don't do it this way, the dev will have SubF2, SubF3 just as a loose folder, and they'll need to create their own structure.